# Returning responses randomly from wiremock

Tags: java, testing, wiremock

I need to return a random response out of a predefined set each time the same wiremock endpoint is called. How can I do it?

Comment: Hi - you have a score of 522. You should know how to come up with questions ^^
Code, errors, something to show us ...

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved by using Response Templating (please see the [official documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/) for more information). I will assume that you are using Wiremock Standalone. The first thing that you need to do is to enable response templating, so you need to run Wiremock using `--global-response-templating` option. For example:

```
java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.27.2.jar --global-response-templating
```

Please note that you can also use local templating (if you want to configure templating only for a specific mock) using the option `--local-response-templating`

The next thing is to create a mock that uses Handlebar bars helpers, in your case you can generate a random string like this:

```
    {
    "request": {
        "urlPath": "/templated"
    },
    "response": {
        "body": "{{randomValue length=33 type='ALPHANUMERIC'}}",
        "transformers": ["response-template"],
        "status" : 200
    }
}
```

That's it. Every time that you call `/templated` resource you should get a different alphanumeric string. Again you can have a look to the documentation under "Random value helper" section to see which helper suits you better.